# Is there any way i can achieve this step bar?

Tags: android

I am trying to make this type of step bar as in the picture but i am unable to do it.Please Suggest some way to achieve it.[image]

I have tried various libraries like https://github.com/shuhart/StepView but i cannot get the desired results.

Comment: What's your desired result?

Comment: I want this type of layout the blocks will contains some text i want the user the update their status by click them.

Comment: Use two progress bars and 8 imageviews+textviews , then depending on the progress update your bar with the relevant percentage (33% increments) and change the colour of the views.

Comment: @halimSol What is `this kind of layout`, `some text` and `them`? I think the library is enough for the feature you want to achieve.

Comment: i meant i want to make something like a stepbar, the user will click the circled buttons to update there status and the bar will move accordingly.

Comment: I found another library to implement such step bar, please check https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar

Comment: c-an thanks for your reply i'll use your proposed logic for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code to get you going:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        android:progress="33"
        android:progressTint="@color/green"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/accent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/accent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.166"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/accent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/accent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just stylise the views accordingly and set click listeners to the imageViews. Then programmatically set the progress of the bar to the desired percentage.

```
imageview2.setOnCLickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setProgress(33);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks its the same as suggested by c-an above so i checked it and its works thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like StateProgressBar it is an Android library to realize the various states and transitions in a ProgressBar as per your requirement

https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar

Add Dependancy

```html
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:1.0.0'
}
```

Add XML

```html
<com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar.StateProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:spb_currentStateNumber="three"
    app:spb_maxStateNumber="four"
    app:spb_stateBackgroundColor="#BDBDBD"
    app:spb_stateForegroundColor="#009688"
    app:spb_stateNumberBackgroundColor="#808080"
    app:spb_stateNumberForegroundColor="#eeeeee"
    app:spb_currentStateDescriptionColor="#009688"
    app:spb_stateDescriptionColor="#808080"
    app:spb_animateToCurrentProgressState="true"
    app:spb_checkStateCompleted="true"/>
```

Add in your Activity

```html
String[] descriptionData = {"Details", "Status", "Photo", "Confirm"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    StateProgressBar stateProgressBar = (StateProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.your_state_progress_bar_id);
    stateProgressBar.setStateDescriptionData(descriptionData);

}
```

Attribute code referred to from https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar